# Android: Horizontal Scroll for ExpandableListView Childs

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have to implement Horizontal scroll view for Child elements of ExpandableListView, now the child elements are shown in Vertical orientation.

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/myGroupListView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:divider="@color/navDrawerIcon"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

item_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_808088_36dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groupMemberList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Group Member"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

item_group_child.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sharedCardImage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_card_xsmall_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_card_xsmall_height"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sharedBalAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sharedCardImage"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to change the `item_group_child.xml` LinearLayout orientation into horizontal, but no luck.

`item_group.xml` should be displayed in vertical way, it works, `item_group_child.xml` should be horizontal way, so the user can scroll child items horizontally. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not with a stock `ExpandableListView`.  `ExpandableListView` is just a regular vertical `ListView` where the `ExpandableListAdapter` handles adding/removing the list items based on the group expand/collapse events.

If you want horizontally scrolling children, then you need to set up your `ExpandableListAdapter` so that each group has just one possible child view, and when that child view is created, it has a horizontal scrolling view that will contain all the group's children.

Comment: ```ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyGroupContactAdapter(MyGroupActivity.this, sharedUsersList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);``` I tried with ExpandableListAdapter, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can achieve this with `CustomHorizontalListView`. see this [link](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView). Just Implement it on your `getChildView()`. I am just customize my `horizontalListView` from above link. see following code:
This is your `group_child_item.xml`

```
<com.customlayout.HorizontalListView 
    android:id="@+id/horizontalListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@color/gray_d7"
    android:padding="20dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</com.customlayout.HorizontalListView>
```

Now inflate above xml into your `getChildView()`:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastchild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ChildHolder childHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_child_item, null, false);
            childHolder = new ChildHolder();
            childHolder.horizontalListView = (HorizontalListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.horizontalListView);

            convertView.setTag(childHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

HorizontalListViewAdapter horizontalListAdapter = new ModuleRoomHorizontalListAdapter(context, groupList, groupPosition);
        ChildHolder.horizontalListView.setAdapter(horizontalListAdapter);

        return convertView;
    }


    private static class ChildHolder
    {
        HorizontalListView horizontalListView;
    }
```

Now implement your `item_group_child.xml` file for horizontalListViewChild and inflate in `getView` of `HorizontalListAdapter`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sharedCardImage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_card_xsmall_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_card_xsmall_height"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sharedBalAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sharedCardImage"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center" />


</LinearLayout>
```

HorizontalListAdapter:

```
public class HorizontalListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Groups> mGroupListList;
    private int mGroupPosition;



    public HorizontalListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Groups> mGroupListList, int mGroupPosition) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mGroupListList = mGroupListList;
        this.mGroupPosition = mGroupPosition;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mGroupListList.get(mGroupPosition).getChildList().size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return mGroupListList.get(mGroupPosition).getChildList().get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_group_child, null, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Implement Your code here what functionality you need.

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txtName;

    }
}
```

Hope it helps you. If you have any issues let me know

Comment: Should i implement the above library (https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView) to implement this?

Comment: Ya, Just try one demo project and add library in your demo. and make sure that your demo is running perfectly then customize at your own risk. but I suggest that if you do not need another customizing things in 'horizontalListView' then implement as it is.

Comment: Why don't we try RecyclerView instead of HorizontalListView?

Comment: Done it with RecyclerView for child elements with your idea.

Comment: thanks i am getting new way...could you please correct it, if someone have same problem then it might be helfull for that person.

Comment: I will push the sample code in github and share the link. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Sam idea, done the Horizontal scroll for child elements of ExpandableListView with RecyclerView without any third party plugin.

Demo app: https://github.com/sivailango/ExpandableListView-RecylerChildItems